# What is in the box?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, herbert-west-reanimator

Near the end of “Herbert West, Reanimator,” the title character receives a sealed box, presumably from a series of reanimated men and body parts who seek vengeance. West and the narrator incinerate the box without opening it. The monsters soon break through a wall and haul West away.

What’s in the box? I feel as though there must be a clue in the text but I can’t find it.

Comment: EDIT: I somehow missed the blaringly obvious link at the top of the page, I'm an idiot, ignore me.